# Elasticsearch doc_type and parent_id

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am new to ES (version 6.x), and I have read some changed about it... such as the change in doc_type, which is clearly explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html). But also the change in the parent_id, which has more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/mapping-parent-field.html).

Given that knowledge, and the information obtained by running

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.index()
```

I see that the parameters `index`, `doc_type`, and `body` are mandatory.

```
TypeError: index() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'index', 'doc_type', and 'body'
```

so, why is doc_type needed here? I thought it should be avoided from now on...

Further, when running `help(es.index)` I still see the argument for `parent ID`, which should've been replaced by a `join` field. So why is this not the case?

I assume that I am missing some information, and so I will keep reading on, but maybe you guys can also point me in the right direction. Your help is appreciated :)

PS:
I am sure that I am running version 6.x, because

```
>>> elasticsearch.__version__
(6, 3, 0)
```

Comment: As per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html: 
"Indices created in 6.x only allow a single-type per index. Any name can be used for the type, but there can be only one. The preferred type name is _doc, so that index APIs have the same path as they will have in 7.0: PUT {index}/_doc/{id} and POST {index}/_doc".

So essentially it won't be required in 7.0 but it seems like 6.0 has this middle ground where we still have to provide the type name.

I'm not sure on the second part of your question hence leaving this comment rather than an answer

Comment: @ifo20 - I assume you mean that the `doc_type` field referenced in the question above should be hardcoded to always contain `'_doc'` for any documents inserted into 6.x elasticsearch indexes.  Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @rcronk I understand that is the recommended approach. I think it can be called anything you like (as long as you have only one doctype per index), but '_doc' would be the standard